# oTree - boolean field displayed as button

Tags: otree

I have boolean field and I want to display it as button. The inital value of the field is "NO" and if the user pushes this button the value changes to "YES" and he receives some payoff. It is important that it would be one button the user can push.

I think that my problem is how to display only one button with the initial value - in any way I tried I get 3 buttons - Yes, No, and -----.

This is what I tried:

```
<div id = "1-round" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-lg " data-toggle="buttons" >
{% for value in form.choiceA %}
    <label class="btn btn-primary rounded mr-3 active btn-lg 1-round" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
        {{value}}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

and then I tried this:

```
<div id = "1-round" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle btn-lg " data-toggle="buttons" >
{% for value in form.choiceA %}
    {% if value == "YES" %}
    <label class="btn btn-primary rounded mr-3 active btn-lg 1-round" style="margin-bottom:8px;">
        {{value}}
    </label>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

but in this case nothing was showed.

also I tried the regular way: `{% formfield player.choiceA label="What your answer?" %}`

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us the code for what you have tried, so you can explain where you problem actually is.